# Can't get Edimax EW-7822PIC to work

Tags: linux, drivers, debian

I'm running debian on my workstation and I can't get my Edimax EW-7822PIC to work; and on both the cd and the manufacturer website I can only find the Windows drivers. I've seen posts of users with similar problems with the [7822UAC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368015/problem-with-building-compiling-a-driver-for-edimax-wireless-adapter-ew-7822uac), but I doubt the drivers will work the same.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: you will need to post the output of `lspci -vvn | grep -e net` and of `lshw -C net`. After this, perhaps something more will be needed.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae
Hope this helps:

`00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I218-V [8086:15a1] (rev 05)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:7885]
        Kernel driver in use: e1000e

0a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8812AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8812] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Device [7392:d822]

ff:0b.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Haswell-E R3 QPI Link 0 & 1 Monitoring [8086:2f81] (rev 02)`

Comment: Yes it is: there is no Linux driver for this dongle, see https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Edimax_EW-7822MAC. If you had posted the output of the second command I gave you, you would have seen that there is no driver installed.

Comment: Alrighty so now I am seeing `0a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8812AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8812] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Device [7392:d822]
        Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae
`
And I can see networks in the area but, when I try to connect to a network it fails, do you think this might be an issue with the realtek driver?

Comment: Have you installed its firmware? `sudo apt-get install firmware-realtek`

Comment: I have indeed, I just double checked and I have 'firmware realtek is already the newest version' as I would expect as I did it yesterday.

Comment: Error messages with `dmesg`?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Sorry for the late reply. The output from the `dmesg` is a bit large and I am having difficulty trying to unpick what is going on as it seems to be connecting with some but not others. Also I am using another device in order to connect to my network and converse on here. Do you mind if I send you the output of the `dmesg` in a private message?